# UITableViewCell format reused after deletion

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I subclassed UITableViewCell.  Basically what happens is that when you press the UITableViewCell drawing on the cell's layer occurs causing the cell to appear different.  However, when I delete a cell, that drawing drops to the cell below it.  This to me seems to indicate that the cell's format is getting re-used as would be normal.  Thus I redrew the cell in CellForRowAtIndexPath as one can see below...

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
AGProgressViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//NSLog(@"progress value = %f", [cell.progress floatValue]);

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[AGProgressViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

Task * task = nil;

if (indexPath.section == 0){
    task = [self.tasksByDay[@"anyday"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else if (indexPath.section == 1){
    task = [self.tasksByDay[@"monday"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else if (indexPath.section == 2){
    task = [self.tasksByDay[@"tuesday"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else if (indexPath.section == 3){
    task = [self.tasksByDay[@"wednesday"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else if (indexPath.section == 4){
    task = [self.tasksByDay[@"thursday"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else if (indexPath.section == 5){
    task = [self.tasksByDay[@"friday"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else if (indexPath.section == 6){
    task = [self.tasksByDay[@"saturday"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else if (indexPath.section == 7){
    task = [self.tasksByDay[@"sunday"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
cell.progress = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([task.timeSpent floatValue]/[task.time floatValue])];
// this is calling the redrawing method in the cell
[cell drawFillInAtPercent:[task.timeSpent floatValue]/[task.time floatValue]];

//NSLog(@"progress value = %f vs. time spent = %f", [cell.progress floatValue], [task.timeSpent floatValue]/[task.time floatValue]);

cell.textLabel.text = task.name;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d minutes",
                             [task.time intValue] - [task.timeSpent intValue]];

return cell;
}
```

However, this did not fix the problem. All those NSLogs showed the cell being at the right level for every re-drawing.  This means, for some reason, the cell that is getting deleted is not getting called in the cellForRowAtIndex path.  The weird thing is that the text labels are changing, simply the custom drawing that I do in the UITableViewCell subclass is not changing.

This is the method that I am calling there in the subclass.

```
-(void) drawFillInAtPercent: (float) percent{
//if (percent > 0){
    NSLog(@"progress layer at percent %f", percent);
    _progressLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    _progressLayer.frame = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x,
                                      self.bounds.origin.y,
                                      self.bounds.size.width * percent,
                                      self.bounds.size.height);
    _progressLayer.colors = @[(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:0/250.0 blue:250.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
    (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:150.0/200.0 green:150.0/200.0 blue:150.0/200.0 alpha:.5] CGColor],
    (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:200.0/200.0 green:200.0/200.0 blue:200.0/200.0 alpha:.5] CGColor],
    (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.3f alpha:0.1f] CGColor]];
    _progressLayer.locations = @[@0.00f, @0.2f, @0.90f, @1.00f];
    [self.layer insertSublayer:_progressLayer atIndex:1];
//}
}
```

I have no idea what is happening, and I don't seem to be able to access the reused cell in order to redraw it.

These are the deletion methods:

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    [self deactivateTimers];
    NSArray * days = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"anyday", @"monday", @"tuesday",       @"wednesday", @"thursday", @"friday", @"saturday", @"sunday", nil];

    Task * task = self.tasksByDay[days[indexPath.section]][indexPath.row];

    if ([task.weekly boolValue]){
        task.finished = [NSNumber numberWithBool:1];
    } else {
        [managedObjectContext deleteObject:task];
    }

    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

    [self grabTasksFromContext];

   }

}

-(void) grabTasksFromContext{
   NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
   NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Task"  
   inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
   [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
   NSError *error;
   NSMutableArray * managedObjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[managedObjectContext  
   executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]];
   int numObjects = [managedObjects count];

   for (int i = 0; i < numObjects; i ++){
       Task * task = [managedObjects objectAtIndex:i];
       NSLog(@"name %@", task.name);
    // if the task is finished we don't want it to be displayed in the list
       if ([task.finished boolValue]){
           NSLog(@"finished");
           [managedObjects removeObject:task];
           i -= 1;
           numObjects -= 1;
       }
    }

    self.tasks = managedObjects;

// This implementation is pretty ugly
// I'm sorry about that and will fix it in the future
// probably the more attractive way to do this is to make an array of the days, and then              cycle through that and check through the array of tasks
monday = tuesday = wednesday = thursday = friday = saturday = sunday = anyday = 0;

NSMutableArray * mondayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray * tuesdayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray * wednesdayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray * thursdayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray * fridayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray * saturdayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray * sundayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray * anydayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (Task * task in self.tasks){
    if ([task.day isEqualToString:@"monday"]){
        mondayArray[monday] = task;
        monday++;
    } else if ([task.day isEqualToString:@"tuesday"]){
        tuesdayArray[tuesday] = task;
        tuesday++;
    } else if ([task.day isEqualToString:@"wednesday"]){
        wednesdayArray[wednesday] = task;
        wednesday++;
    } else if ([task.day isEqualToString:@"thursday"]){
        thursdayArray[thursday] = task;
        thursday++;
    } else if ([task.day isEqualToString:@"friday"]){
        fridayArray[friday] = task;
        friday++;
    } else if ([task.day isEqualToString:@"saturday"]){
        saturdayArray[saturday] = task;
        saturday++;
    } else if ([task.day isEqualToString:@"sunday"]){
        sundayArray[sunday] = task;
        sunday++;
    } else {
        anydayArray[anyday] = task;
        anyday++;
    }
 }

    self.tasksByDay = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: mondayArray,@"monday",     
    tuesdayArray, @"tuesday", wednesdayArray, @"wednesday", thursdayArray, @"thursday",   
    fridayArray, @"friday", saturdayArray, @"saturday", sundayArray, @"sunday", 
    anydayArray, @"anyday", nil];

     [self.tableView reloadData];
 }
```

Any help or thoughts on what is happening would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, when I delete a cell, that drawing drops to the cell below it.

This is the key observation: it indicates to me that at the time the redraw is happening, the model (i.e. your `self.tasksByDay[dayName]`) has *not* been updated yet. When a cell at a certain row is deleted, the `taskByDay` for the corresponding day needs to be updated to remove the corresponding row from the `NSArray`. If this does not happen, the data for the deleted task would influence the drawing of a cell at the next index, thus the visuals wold appear to "drop" by one row. From your description it sounds like this is precisely what is happening.

You need to make sure that by the time the table is refreshed (or the notification of a cell deletion is sent to the `UITableView`) the model has been updated already to not have the row being deleted. This way the table visuals would update as you expect them to.

Not directly related to the problem, but if you create an array

```
NSArray *dayName = @[@"anyday", @"monday", @"tuesday", @"wednesday", etc.];
```

you can replace the long chain of `if`s with

```
task = [self.tasksByDay[dayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

The other problem in your code is that every time that you call `drawFillInAtPercent:`, a new `CAGradientLayer` is added. As you scroll up and down, reused cells accumulate new layers without ever getting rid of the previously added ones. You need to change your code to add the gradient layer only once, and then reusing the existing one inside your `drawFillInAtPercent:` method. For example, you can add the layer in the designated initializer of the `AGProgressViewCell`, assigning it to `_progressLayer` instance variable, and adding it to the layer hierarchy once. From then on, `drawFillInAtPercent:` would change the existing `_progressLayer`, rather than creating new ones each time.

Comment: Hmm this is confusing to me because I thought I did change the model before reloading the table... in the deletion I modify the object in the context, save the context, and then call a method I wrote [self grabTasksFromContext] that resets the model, and ends with [self.tableview reloadData] after the model is reset.  I don't understand how the view would be redrawing itself before the task has been modified in the model.

Comment: @AdamG You may want to update your question with your deletion method then, because the key to the problem is likely to be three.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help so far, and I will definitely make that change  to make my code more readable. I added the deletion code.

Comment: @AdamG Wow, that's a lot of code! My "debugerless" debugging skills are definitely failing me. What you can do to help you debug, though, is adding a piece of code that `NSLog`s the `tasksByDay` for you in a way that makes it easy to read, and calling this code right before the `[self.tableView reloadData]` call. This way you would see the precise state of your model immediately before the data is reloaded, letting you catch the discrepancy between what you see and what you expected to see.

Comment: I put an NSLog right before the [self.tableView reloadData] call that would let me see the names of all the different tasks.  I added a task that was called "special task" and deleted it.  It was not in the model before the method was called.  :/.

Comment: So I did some further debugging, and I added a lot more tasks and scrolled up and down after the cell had been modified, and suddenly the format was jumping around all over the place.  So it seems like, for some reason, the method that is supposed to appropriately redraw the view is not activating.

Comment: @AdamG I updated the answer with a suggestion that should take care of the issues related to reusing the cell object.